# clover not picking up certain objects

Tags: java, clover

I noticed clover is not picking up results for 1 particular class that I have.
Its a domain object that has 3 overloaded constructors.

It shows up in the clover reports as having 0% coverage.
I even wrote a dummy test case to test all the constructors, accessor methods etc and it stilled showed up as having 0% coverage

Other objects in the same package are picked up perfectly ok by clover

is there anything I need to do to ensure that this object is picked up by clover?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the compilation unit of the relevant class doesn't have a CLOVER:OFF directive, and check to make sure the classfile is being instrumented by Clover.

A couple of years ago, I had a small amount of experience with Clover, and I remember having a problem whereby the coverage data wasn't being written quickly enough. Recommendation from the Atlassian team was to fork each test in a separate JVM, rather than batch them.

It could simply be a bug in Clover's instrumentation, for example. In my experience the team is pretty responsive; might be worthwhile to check on their forums.